# PERCENTRANK.EXC if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to calculate where the rank a number is within a particular range. The value is contained in the range, but within the range there are 2 categories (let's say Red and Green; identifiable through the column next to the column containing the results), as a result, the rank is including both categories, thus, I would like to do a rank if

```
{=if(A:A="Red",PERCENTRANK.EXC(D:D,A10),"")}
```

Comment: I don't have an idea of how percentrank.exc works, but to get the array use: IF(A:A="Red",D:D). Nested in the percentrank.exc formula should give =PERCENTRANK.EXC(IF(A:A="Red",D:D),A10)

Comment: It's not at all a good idea to reference entire columns within an array formula. Try limiting the ranges, e.g. A1:A1000, D1:D1000.

Comment: Indeed, it slows calculations, however in this instance there are not many cases, and I was being lazy.

Comment: You say: "I would like to do a rank if" but you do a "if rank". A "rank if": `{=PERCENTRANK.EXC(IF(A:A="Red",D:D),A10)}`. But if column `A` contains text, "Red" for example, how can `A10` be a number then?

Comment: @XORLX you are right, but with dynamic range adjustments like `{=PERCENTRANK.EXC(IF(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,D:D,1))="Red",D1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D,1))),D10)}` you may get even faster... (but only if the ranges vary in size by a noticeable amount / depends on system)